# Why is Twitter still trading below $54.20?

Tags: stocks

Twitter closed the last trading day (Apr 29th, as of writing this question) at $49.02.

My understanding of the recent developments is that Elon Musk has committed to buying *all* shares of Twitter at $54.20 apiece.

If my understanding is correct, why is it still trading a 10% under that value? And when is the buy back supposed to happen?

If my understanding is not correct, then in what way?

Comment: because the market thinks there's a maybe 30% chance that Musk will come up with some reason not to do this?

Comment: Share price is the price of the last trade executed. Why would you buy for $54.20 if you weren't going to be able to sell it for more than that?

Comment: @user253751 How did you come up with the 30% figure?

Comment: @Flux very rough estimate; the discount is roughly 10%; a 90% chance of $54 and a 10% chance of $0 would warrant a 10% discount off $54; but the chance of Twitter going to $0 is very low so the chance of it not getting to $54 must be higher to justify the same discount.

Comment: [Elon Musk says Twitter deal ‘cannot move forward’ until he has clarity on bot numbers](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/05/17/elon-musk-says-twitter-deal-cannot-move-forward-until-he-has-clarity-on-bot-numbers.html) ... An eccentric and unpredictable billionaire is just kicking the tires.